# Select random record from combobox

Tags: c#-4.0

How to select random item from a combo box, without selecting what is there already in the combobox.

Comment: "What is there in Your Combo box?" can you explain some more.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int newIndex = -1;

do {
    newIndex = random.Next(comboBox.Items.Count);
} while (newIndex == comobBox.SelectedIndex && comboBox.Items.Count > 1);

comobBox.SelectedIndex = random.Next(comboBox.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Random` class to get a random number between 0 and the max amount of items in the combobox. You should get this number repeatedly until you get one that doesn't match what is already selected within the combobox, like so:

```
Random random = new Random();
int newSelectedIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
while (newSelectedIndex == comboBox.SelectedIndex) {
    newSelectedIndex = random.Next(0, comboBox.Items.Count);
}
comboBox.SelectedIndex = newSelectedIndex;
// Item
// comboBox.Items[newSelectedIndex];
```

This may not work C/P'd, as I wrote it from the top of my head and don't have an IDE to test right now, but I hope you get the idea.

**IMPORTANT**: If you only have 1 item which is also selected, this may get into an endless loop...

Answer (score 0):

Basically Combo box has items in string so if you can describe me some clear then we may help more anyway here is sample code 
 n you can do it

```
ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
Random rt = new Random();
string myText = "";
myText = b.Items[rt.Next(0, b.Items.Count - 1)].ToString();
```